# Pass Node.js Express variable to my static javascript files

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

How can I pass one Node.js Express variable to my static JavaScript files? I am trying to do a fetch in my client js, but for that I need 2 ID's that I get from my database. Right now I am cheating this behavior by sending the ID's with the .ejs file. This works, but is far from right.

```
<span id="user_1"><%= user.ID %></span>
<span id="user_2"><%= matchId %></span>

setInterval(function() {
  let test123 = document.querySelector('.chat_history_section_inner').childElementCount;
  let user_1 = document.querySelector('#user_1').innerHTML;
  let user_2 = document.querySelector('#user_2').innerHTML;;
  fetch('/api?s1=' + user_1 + '&r1=' + user_2 + '&s2=' + user_2 + '&r2=' + user_1, {
    method: 'get'
  }).then(function (response) {
    return response.json()
  }).then(function (res) {
    if (res.length > test123) {
      location.reload();
    } else {
      console.log('Your chat is up to date!')
    }
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Instead of returning an `*.ejs` view, you can return a dynamically generated script from the server and include it at the client side just as any other static script. The dynamic script would have ids set to correct values.

Comment: Can I return both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried to pass it directly to the variable?

```
let user_1 = "<%= user.ID %>";
```

If your js file is not rendered by EJS you have to pass it from an ejs rendered file to your function, or you add it as a custom attribute to your html tag and read the attribute from the id - thats similar to your solution.

Comment: Uhm, I like the attributes idea, well I prefer the other option but I don't think it is worth rendering a dynamic JS just for 2 variables. But is it considered ok to use the attributes solution?